# Passing tns:ArrayOfString to SOAP client

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I'm trying to use the api from this service:

```
http://messagingws.payamservice.ir/SendSMS.asmx?WSDL
```

I'm using the php's SOAP client like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://messagingws.payamservice.ir/SendSMS.asmx?WSDL");

$params=array();
$params['PortalCode']='code';
$params['UserName']='user';
$params['PassWord']='pass';
$params['Mobiles']=array('09123456789');
$params['Messages']=array('test');
$params['FlashSMS']=false;
$params['ServerType']=1;

$response = $client->__soapCall('MultiSMSEngine', array($params));
```

but I get "empty message" error, when I try with single mode it works correctly so it seems the problem is with `Mobiles` & `Messages` parameters that are `tns:ArrayOfString`

How can I correctly pass an array as `tns:ArrayOfString` for SOAP ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you can call the method such as `$client->MultiSMSEngine($params)` instead of `$client->__soapCall('MultiSMSEngine', array($params));`.

If you keep your form of call, try `$client->__soapCall('MultiSMSEngine', $params);`

Finally, to ease you the call to any SOAP Web Service, I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to php generator such as [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator)